# open failed: EACCES (Permission denied) while using a FileProvider in onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, permissions, camera, provider

I am trying to get a recently recorded Video in onActivityResult. But I don't understand how this Content Provider works. I am not used to program in Java for Android so it might be a simple thing but I can't solve it myself.

The Question is only how to get the content://media/external/video/media/17877 to a local file using the provider in the app folder where no extra access is needed

This is the Codepart I am Debugging:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ....
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_VIDEO) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    ....
            Uri selectedMediaUri = data.getData();
            String strMediaFile = getRealPathFromURI(getApplicationContext(),selectedMediaUri);
            Log.d("App","got link:"+selectedMediaUri+" File:"+strMediaFile);
            File fileCameraTemp = new File(strCameraTempFile);
            File fileCameraResult = new File(strMediaFile);
            Uri sharedFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "de.xyz.app.fileprovider", fileCameraResult);
            InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(sharedFileUri);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileCameraTemp);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = is.read(buf)) > 0) {
                fos.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            is.close();
            fos.close();
    ....
}
```

I am trying to store the Video File to a local accessible File.

The getRealPathFromURI function:

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
  Cursor cursor = null;
  try {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
  } finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.close();
    }
  }
}
```

So the log output I get is following:

```
App: onActivityResult
D App: CAMERA_REQUEST_VIDEO
D App: No valid strCameraTempFile:/storage/emulated/0/cameraresult.mp4 -> using data
D App: got data
D App: got link:content://media/external/video/media/17877 File:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/20230824_113912.mp4
W System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W System.err:   at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.openInternal(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:315)
W System.err:   at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:220)
W System.err:   at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.openFile(FileProvider.java:566)
W System.err:   at android.content.ContentProvider.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1733)
W System.err:   at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1915)
W System.err:   at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1982)
W System.err:   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:511)
W System.err:   at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1701)
W System.err:   at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1517)
W System.err:   at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:1201)
W System.err:   at de.x.y.App.onActivityResult(App.java:484)
W System.err:   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8300)
W System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5353)
W System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5401)
W System.err:   at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
W System.err:   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
W System.err:   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
W System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
W System.err:   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
W System.err:   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
W System.err:   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
W System.err:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W System.err:   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
W System.err:   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

I have a Provider in my Android Manifest:

```
    <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="v.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">

        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

with following Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
     <external-files-path name="images" path="Pictures"/>
     <cache-path name="cache" path="."/>
     <files-path name="files" path="."/>
     <external-path name="external" path="." />
     <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
     <external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="." />
</paths>
```

I don't know what to do to make this work and hope that somebody can help me with this

The strCameraTempFile is a File in the local App Folder.

Comment: It makes no sense trying to get a real path from a nice uri.

Comment: It also makes no sense using FileProvider to write to a file yourself. FileProvider is for getting an uri and then let the uri be used by a different app.

Comment: That comment helped not at all. This is not the question. The error happens after that as you can see from the logoutput. And the other point is that I need the File to another location as I actually wrote the app in C++ and there I have only access to the local folder not to the URI

Comment: You also did not tell of which startActivityForResult onActivityResult is the result.

Comment: `am trying to store the Video File to a local accessible File.` For me it looks as if you try to over write the original file.

Comment: You are not helping. It is easy to understand that this is not relevant as my question is only how to get the content://media/external/video/media/17877 to a local file using the provider in the app folder (where no extra access is needed)

Comment: Then put what you want on the first lines of your post. Not afterwards in comments. And directly make it clear for what you want it. Including c++ access. And if you want to over write the file then tell it.

Comment: stop trolling. If you had read the whole question with the log it could be understandable but I puttet the question for those who don't read the complete code in the first lines as you suggested. The point where I want to use the local file is irrelevant.

Comment: `how to get the content://media/external/video/media/17877 to a local file ` That is already a local file. It is already on your device. Unclear what you want.

Comment: read the log, the file uri content://media/external/video/media/17877 is inaccessible - PERMISSION DENIED. If I can read it it should be copied to a LOCAL File of the app so the Apps other function can access it without requesting any Permissions. To understand my question you need basic knowledge how after Android Q the Permissions for certain Folders are managed

Comment: You are missing basic knowledge how to read the logcat. The message comes from using uri of FilePrivider not from using original uri. See subject of your post.

Comment: `de.x.y.App.onActivityResult(App.java:484)`

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjnnJyd-feAAxWATmwGHf_DBiEQFnoECA0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F8854359%2Fexception-open-failed-eacces-permission-denied-on-android&usg=AOvVaw1CGqAaQPKl9ta_LWszaURK&opi=89978449

Comment: check that link may be you will get solution

Comment: android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" are u used that line in your manifest

Comment: <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" /> this one also check\

Comment: <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

Comment: provider also check

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!--    <external-path name="OctopusDriver" path="OctopusDriver/"/>-->
    <external-path name="yourappname" path="Android/data/in.yourpackgename.android/files/Images/Pictures/Yourappname/"/>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    <files-path path="Images/" name="Pictures" />
</paths>

Comment: Thanks but it was the problem blackapps mentioned. I had another path that was not meant to be inserted as the tempfile path. Just something that was missed after a long day

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The correction mentioned by @blackapps in the comments (although he became a little bit insolent) was the key. After he read my post especially the logcat output in detail he found what I did not read precise enough. It was something not shown in my code snipped above.

I missed that the strCameraTempFile was filled with a not accessible path (I changed it while debugging before using the Fileprovider). So the above posted code is correct but the input for strCameraTempFile should be a reachable path e.g. like getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

> The getRealPathFromURI function

Delete that function.

Then, replace:

```java
            Uri sharedFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "de.xyz.app.fileprovider", fileCameraResult);
            InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(sharedFileUri);
```

with:

```java
            InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedMediaUri);
```

At this point, your code to copy the content into the filesystem path identified as `fileCameraTemp` should work better. You can also remove the rest of your `FileProvider` configuration, along with the now-unused variables in your existing code.

Comment: Thanks but still no luck. I got the Access denied again. As I see it in the Android Description I will need a Fileprovider to be allowed to get the Sourcefile from the Phones Media Folder (content://media/external/video/media/17877). But I didn't find any good description on how to use it.